What is the default font of the Eisvogel pandoc template?
I'm writing a university thesis using the Eisvogel template. I will have to add to the text some plots generated in R, and for this reason I want the font of the plots to be the same as the body of the text.
I think the template uses the Latin Modern Sans font, because of the "\usepackage{lmodern}"(line 160 in the Eisvogel.tex file); however, i downloaded the Latin Modern Sans font and, using this font family in my R plots, i can see that there are some differences in the characters (for example in the "a"s and the "2"s).
My question is: does anyone know what is the default font used in this template?
Thanks in advance

if you have a pdf, the pdffonts utility or your pdf viewer would list all fonts used

it uses different fonts for text and math and different fonts for pdftex, xetex and luatex, you have not said what you are using, but mostly it seems to use latin modern variants.

Generally you do not have to worry about what font is using LaTeX, just use knitr with the tikz device and the R plot will use the main document  font  automatically. See here, for instance.
